# Triying to create a JS random dungeon generator

Tags: javascript, html, random

**I'm triying to create a game that generates a random dungeon in a map; I'm having trouble generating the rooms and having them connect between themselves.**

I'm triying to create an algorithm that generates a room once a player has passed through a door; I have created a variable size map using  and I have created the first room; but i've got no idea on how to start generating new rooms using the first room as a reference and how to solve the various problems random dungeon generators have (having rooms collide with the map limit or another room, checking if there is enough space for a room (and not creating a door if there isn't enough), having rooms reuse the doors that another room has placed, etc.). The idea I had in mind for creating the rooms is that once the player steps on a door; the algorythm runs a function to calculate the distance between the player and the closest wall (from a room or the map limit); once the generator knows the maximum size a room can have in that space; it rolls a random number to determine the width and heigth the room will have (under some parameters); when the room generates, it will have 4 doors; one in each direction, by doing that i can eliminate the possibiliy of having an unaccesible room. I'll leave the code I have developed below; any help or ideas you can give me on how to do this will be great. Thanks for your attention :) .

````
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Mi primera página</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    let mapa = [];
    let ancho;
    let alto;
    let zoom;

    function crearMapa(){
        var color='';
        var cuadro=zoom;

        zoom.oninput=cuadro; 

        document.getElementById('pantalla').innerHTML = ''; 
        mapa = [];
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'mesa';
        div.style.width = ancho*cuadro + 'px';
        div.style.height = alto*cuadro + 'px';

        for (var j=0;j<alto;j++){

            let fila = [];

            for(var i=0;i<ancho;i++){
                if((i+j)%2==0) color='#ffffff'; else color='#cccccc';

                let casilla = document.createElement('div');
                casilla.id = 'cuadro-x-y';
                casilla.style.width = cuadro + 'px';
                casilla.style.height = cuadro + 'px';
                casilla.style.float = 'left';
                casilla.style.backgroundColor = color;

                fila.push(casilla);
                div.appendChild(casilla);
            }
            mapa.push(fila);
        }

        document.getElementById('pantalla').appendChild(div);
    }


    function pintaMapa(){
        ancho=parseInt(document.getElementById('ancho').value);
        alto=parseInt(document.getElementById('alto').value);
        zoom=document.getElementById('slider').value;

        crearMapa(); 
        generaSalaInicial();
    }

const MAX_ALTURA = 10;
const MAX_ANCHURA = 10;
const MIN_ALTURA = 5;
const MIN_ANCHURA = 5;
const MURO = 'red';
const MURO2 = 'green';
const MURO3 = 'blue';



function generaAltura() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_ALTURA + MIN_ALTURA);
}

function generaAnchura() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_ANCHURA + MIN_ANCHURA);
}

    let altura;
    let anchura;
function generaSalaInicial() {
     altura = generaAltura();
     anchura = generaAnchura();
    let anchura0 = 0;
    let altura0 = 0;
    let mitadAltura = Math.trunc(altura / 2);
    let mitadAnchura = Math.trunc(anchura / 2);

    for (let i = 0; i <= anchura; i++) {
            mapa[anchura0][i].style.backgroundColor = MURO;
        if (i != mitadAnchura) {
            mapa[altura][i].style.backgroundColor = MURO;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= altura; i++) {
            mapa[i][altura0].style.backgroundColor = MURO;
        if (i != mitadAltura) {
            mapa[i][anchura].style.backgroundColor = MURO;
        }
    }

}


var disDer;
var disIzq;
var disArr;
var disAbj;

function distDer(){
         disDer = ancho - anchura - 1 ;
}

function distIzq(){//broken
         disIzq = anchura + 1;
}

function distArr(){//broken
         disArr = altura + 1;
}

function distAbj(){
         disAbj = alto - altura - 1;
}

function genHabDer(){//broken

    distDer()
    alert(disDer)

    let anchura0 = anchura +1;
    let altura0 = altura +1;
altura = generaAltura();
anchura = generaAnchura();
    let mitadAltura = Math.trunc(altura / 2);
    let mitadAnchura = Math.trunc(anchura / 2);
    for (let i = 0; i <= anchura; i++) {
            mapa[anchura0][i].style.backgroundColor = MURO2;
        if (i != mitadAnchura) {
            mapa[altura][i].style.backgroundColor = MURO2;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= altura; i++) {
            mapa[i][altura0].style.backgroundColor = MURO2;
        if (i != mitadAltura) {
            mapa[i][anchura].style.backgroundColor = MURO2;
        }
    }



}   


    </script>
 </head>
 <body onkeypress="mover(event)">


    AnchoMapa (en cuadritos): <input type="text" id="ancho" value="40"><br>
    AltoMapa (en cuadritos): <input type="text" id="alto" value="40"><br>
    Tamaño de la cuadricula (zoom) (se mide en pixels):<input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="50" value="10"  onchange="pintaMapa()">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Crear Mapa" onclick="pintaMapa()"><br>
    <div id="pantalla"></div>

 </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Hi @alanchede.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That is quite a large block of text without a clear single question.  Could you edit your post to highlight what you are asking in one sentence?  It needs to be something specific that people can post one answer for; (i.e. not asking for general advice)

Comment: Okay, sorry for making this huge block of text, this is the first time I'm asking something and I'm quite lost